# Taking the integral with absolute value and the floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> I have never integrated using the floor function before, so I just need help starting the following problem.
>   $$\int_{3}^{4} \frac{|x-1|}{\lfloor 2x-5 \rfloor} dx =?$$

Comment: In this interval the absolute value of $x-1$ is $x-1$, Moreover the floor of $2x-5$ is either $3$ or $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$\int_{3}^{4} \frac{x-1}{\lfloor 2x-5 \rfloor} dx = \int_{3}^{3.5} \frac{x-1}{1} dx+ \int_{3.5}^{4} \frac{x-1}{2} dx.$$